# Hash keeps failing to iterate

Tags: ruby

I am trying to iterate through a folder, select all the files that end in .bowtie.txt, count the number of lines, and then write the number of lines with the filename it came from, to a hash (or even better an external csv but a hash will do for now). I was provided with this solution

```
Dir['/Volumes/.../*.bowtie.txt'].inject({}) do |memo, file|
  memo[file] = File.readlines(file).select do |line| 
                 line =~ /^[0-9]+\s*(\+|\-)/ # only those, matching
               end.count
  puts memo
end
```

however this has to odd behaviour of selecting a file, then giving me one hash before it fails as follows:

```
Me:~ me$ ruby /Users/me/Desktop/SequencingScripts/Plots/GeneralScripts/DistinctPositions.rb
{"/Volumes/SeagateBackupPlusDriv/SequencingRawFiles/TumourOesophagealOCCAMS/SequencingScripts/3finalcounts/SLX-9279.GoodDysplasia.FSeqA_BEST2_NEW_0204_LessThan10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz.bowtie.txt"=>31312}
/Users/me/Desktop/SequencingScripts/Plots/GeneralScripts/DistinctPositions.rb:5:in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/me/Desktop/SequencingScripts/Plots/GeneralScripts/DistinctPositions.rb:4:in `each'
        from /Users/me/Desktop/SequencingScripts/Plots/GeneralScripts/DistinctPositions.rb:4:in `inject'
        from /Users/me/Desktop/SequencingScripts/Plots/GeneralScripts/DistinctPositions.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

when I don't use `puts memo` I don't get an error but I also don't get any output to the terminal. How do I get what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use inject in this context, you need to return your memo object at the end.  So in your example, that would look like:

```
Dir['/Volumes/.../*.bowtie.txt'].inject({}) do |memo, file|
  memo[file] = File.readlines(file).select do |line| 
                 line =~ /^[0-9]+\s*(\+|\-)/ # only those, matching
               end.count
  puts memo
  memo
end
```

Here's a contrived example to illustrate the same error & resolution:

```
[1] pry(main)> [1, 2, 3].inject({}) { |hash, num| hash[num] = 1 }
NoMethodError: undefined method []= for 1:Fixnum
[2] pry(main)> [1, 2, 3].inject({}) { |hash, num| hash[num] = 1; hash }
=> {1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>1}
```

Comment: Great. I knew it was something simple. Thanks

Comment: Or just use a friendlier `each_with_object`, which doesn't require returning memo :)

Answer (score 1):

if you use `inject` your block should ALWAYS return updated `memo` in the last line. In your case during the second iteration memo is equal to last line so to the result of puts memo

```
Dir['/Volumes/.../*.bowtie.txt'].inject({}) do |memo, file|
  memo[file] = File.readlines(file).select do |line| 
                 line =~ /^[0-9]+\s*(\+|\-)/ # only those, matching
               end.count
  puts memo
  memo
end
```